# Select all text inside memo independent of click position

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm experiencing some problems programmatically selecting all the text inside a `TMemo` component

I have an `OnClick` event handler that looks something like this

```
procedure TForm8.Memo1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.SelectAll;
end;
```

If I click inside the memo where the text ends, everything is selected.

But If I click somewhere at a position before where the text ends, the selection goes from 0 to the clicked position instead of selecting everything.

I have tried messing around with the memo's `SelStart`, `SetLength` and `CaretPosition` properties before calling `SelectAll`, but I haven't got this to work.

Interestingly enough, when I put a breakpoint inside the `TCustomMemo.SelectAll` procedure and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> then `SelectAll` is also called inside `TStyledMemo.KeyDown`, but then everything is selected. It seems clicking inside the memo does something that makes `SelectAll` behave differently somehow.

I'm on Delphi 11.0

Does anybody know if it's possible what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Added a `TMemo` to an FMX form. At runtime I added text by both typing and copy paste. No matter where I click within the `TMeme`, all text is selected. I did my test with Delphi XE7, didn't bother to test with others as you didn't bother to say which version you are using.

Comment: After all, I tried also with Delphi 10.4 and indeed, the problem shows up. Have you checked / reported to Embarcadero quality portal? If not, please do.

Comment: @TomBrunberg Sorry for not mentioning my Delphi version. I'm on 11.0. I've put it in the question now also. I have not been on Embarcadero quality portal yet, but I'll check it out. Thank you!

Comment: I've discussed the problem with my colleague and he found a workaround. If you put `Memo1.SelectAll;` in a `TThread.ForceQueue` it works inside the on click handler.